# React unable to use useEffect with setState inside function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a scenario where an async function is called on `button click` and the return value is setting the state value. After that, another function is called which needs the previously set value. As it is inside function I am not able to use `useEffect`. How to achieve this?

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

const handleSignIn = async () => {

    const result = await Google.logInAsync(config);
    const { type, idToken } = result;

    setUser(result?.user);

    if (type === "success") {

        AuthService.googleSignIn(idToken)
          .then((result) => {
              const displayName = `${user?.givenName} ${user?.familyName}`;

              signIn({
                 uid: user.uid,
                 displayName: displayName,
                 photoURL: user.photoUrl,
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
      });
  }
};
```

Here, `handleSignIn` is called on the button click and `user` state value is set from the result achieved from the `Google.logInAsync`. Then `AuthService.googleSignIn` is called and when success the `user` object is used there but it not available sometimes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: @cbr, Please spend some time to see the question carefully before opting to close :) The function I've to call in the button click. Are functions inside `useEffect` are accessible in render??

Comment: I linked that post because inside `if (type === "success")`, you access the `user` variable which is going to be null, because `setUser(result?.user)` will not synchronously update the value inside the function's closure. You'd want to do assign `result.user` into a local variable there and use that variable instead in the `.then` handler. What exactly do you need the useEffect for? Do you mean you want to move the functionality from inside `if (type === "success")` into a useEffect hook?

Comment: @cdr, just the local variable will suffice. Thanks

Comment: You can also just use the `result` variable from `Google.logInAsync` if you rename the `result` parameter from `AuthService.googleSignIn` so it  doesn't shadow the other `result` which you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cbr's comment hits the nail on the head.  You need to wrap everything following `setUser` in its own `useEffect`, which will depend on the `user` state variable.  Like this:

```js
const [result, setResult] = React.useState(null);

const handleSignIn = async () => {

    const result = await Google.logInAsync(config);
    setUser(result);

};

useEffect( () => {

  if (result) {

    const { type, idToken, user } = result;

    if (type === "success") {

        AuthService.googleSignIn(idToken)
          .then((result) => {
              const displayName = `${user?.givenName} ${user?.familyName}`;

              signIn({
                 uid: user.uid,
                 displayName: displayName,
                 photoURL: user.photoUrl,
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
          });
    }

  }

}, [result])
```

What happens here is that your `handleSignIn` sets the `user` variable.  Your `useEffect` runs whenever the `user` variable is updated.  If it exists, it will run your `AuthService` code with the new `user` value.

Alternatively, you can skip using `useEffect` altogether by just referencing your `result.user` directly.  Extract it from `result` along with the `type` and `idToken`, and use it directly.  You can still save it to state with your `setUser` function if you need it later:

```js
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

const handleSignIn = async () => {

    const result = await Google.logInAsync(config);
    const { type, idToken, user } = result;

    setUser(user);

    if (type === "success") {

        AuthService.googleSignIn(idToken)
          .then((result) => {
              const displayName = `${user?.givenName} ${user?.familyName}`;

              signIn({
                 uid: user.uid,
                 displayName: displayName,
                 photoURL: user.photoUrl,
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: `const { type, idToken } = result;` is from `result` and not `const { type, idToken } = user;`

Comment: you are right.  i modified things a little bit.  now the state variable is the entire `result`, and you can extract the `user` from it.  the concept is the same though

Comment: @cbr is the real hero here.  side question: i see you are using the result?.user syntax.  I've not seen that before, except in an article talking about ES20, which I wasn't aware was really being used yet.  what is that syntax?

Comment: That is for preventing `null` exception. Just checking the property existence and accessing it.